# Calling Javascript External File in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use this script on a basic HTML page, though I cannot get it to run. 
Here is a JSFiddle of the JS working. http://jsfiddle.net/ChristianL/AVyND/

The Fiddle actually contains the javascript code necessary.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="window.js"></script>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I just would like it call the script on load. Please, refer to the Fiddle for the JS code if necessary.

Update: I have fixed the original issue in my script tag. It was just a typo. The main problem of getting this script to run still remains. I would like for it to automatically execute when a user loads the page.

Comment: editing your post to no longer include the problem is really very bad, it invalidates all of the answers that have been given...

Comment: My guess is the fact that the window.js file is not where you think it is.

Comment: epascarello The window.js file is located in the same folder as index.html.
@DrCord I'm not sure what you're referring to. The problem still remains. That was not the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has errors in it. Not sure if this is a typo.

Here it is again fixed up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="window.js"></script>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

If you would like to run the `alert()` on `load`, you could modify the script you linked to in the jsFiddle like so:

```
window.onload = function(){
    alert(
        'OS: ' + jscd.os +' '+ jscd.osVersion + '\n'+
        'Browser: ' + jscd.browser +' '+ jscd.browserVersion + '\n' + 
        'Mobile: ' + jscd.mobile + '\n' +
        'Flash: ' + jscd.flashVersion + '\n' +
        'Cookies: ' + jscd.cookies + '\n' +
        'Screen Size: ' + jscd.screen
    );
};
```

After recent comments, may I suggest you try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>My First Heading</h1>
        <p>My first paragraph.</p>
        <script src="http://javascript.thecodecanvas.com/window.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

I basically changed the `src` of the `script` tag to point to the absolute URL, just to be sure you're looking in the correct place.

However, I noticed the page link you gave of your example, does indeed appear to work, so perhaps your issue lies with the browser you are using? I have tested this in Firefox and the alert pops up as expected.

I did notice though, that the `window.onload` modification I suggested has not been made in your script, contrary to what you said.

This script appears to be doing a lot of 'sniffing' which is generally considered bad practice these days, as it can be riddled with issues (perhaps what you're seeing here). If you're trying to account for different features, may I suggest you use something like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)? It's a much better approach at dealing with inconsistent browsers; re **JS** and **CSS** capabilities than sniffing versions yourself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I changed the JS function to what you gave me, although it's still not popping up. Here is the URL: http://javascript.thecodecanvas.com/
Here is the URL of the JS: http://javascript.thecodecanvas.com/window.js

Comment: I managed to figure it out. Instead of using the window.onLoad I changed it to the alert that is on the JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

try 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="window.js"></script>`
instead of
`<script type="text/javascript"> src="window.js"</script>`

Comment: Your src attribute is out of the script tag

Answer (score 0):

Your script tag is not correctly formated.

Here is how it should be:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="window.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the src attribute into the script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="window.js"></script>
```